# Buying domain using API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, dns

I've been googling for more than 2 weeks to find any Rails code working with OpenSRS API, but I couldn't find any good solution at all.

Could anyone give me some example or references of using OpenSRS API with Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some quick browsing on the OpenSRS site, I found this gem. start here, definitely:

https://github.com/voxxit/opensrs

If you want to write it all yourself, the ruby toolkit is on this page: http://www.opensrs.com/site/resources/documentation/api#api

But really, the opensrs gem looks like it's all you'll need.

Comment: I am working on this gem as well, but it doesn't provide enough example. That's why I wonder if there anyone else used to work with this gem.